# Can't migrate caliburn Bootstrapper<T> class to version 2.0+

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro, bootstrapper

I have the following problem: In one project I use, caliburn is used, but the code is not up to date.

I found this line in the changelog of caliburn, which should solve the problem:

**Bootstrapper<T>** has been removed. Use **BootstrapperBase** and override **OnStartup** with a call to **DisplayRootViewFor<T>()** instead.

In the project the code is still like this:

```
public class Bootstrapper : Caliburn.Micro.Bootstrapper<MvvmCameraDemo.ViewModels.ShellViewModel>
    {
    }
```

This of course does not work anymore because BootstrapperBase has no argument `<T>` in the new version of caliburn.

I am not so familiar with coding, so maybe one of you guys can help me, how to replace the old Class with the new one.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty well there. Instead of specifying the root view model with the base class, you display it in the `OnStartup` method instead.

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
public class Bootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    public Bootstrapper()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    // More overrides here...

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayRootViewFor<MvvmCameraDemo.ViewModels.ShellViewModel>();
    }
}
```